# Finding a record, the last record with the same id_hash, and recording the time difference of the two records in the column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a query for oracle, in it I will query the table. I want to rework this request, I have a column status. There are 2 events in the status: START and Stop, I also have a hash column, in which the key of this task is being executed. This hash can be repeated

```html
select id, status, date_cr,hesh from SEC_ROUTE
```

my answer:

```html
id   status           date_cr                hesh
9    STOP             26.03.2020 14:45:41    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93123    
8    START            26.03.2020 12:23:47    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93127
7    STOP             26.03.2020 11:12:41    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93111  
6    START            26.03.2020 10:56:40    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93111
5    STOP             26.03.2020 10:23:41    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93B09
4    START            26.03.2020 08:13:40    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93B09
3    START            26.03.2020 07:23:41    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93123
2    STOP             26.03.2020 06:18:56    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93123
1    START            26.03.2020 04:12:23    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93123
```

I want the STATUS column, this is the status of the stops, to record the difference between the beginning and the end of work
example(The format of recording the difference is not fundamental):

```html
    id  status             date_cr                hesh
    9   STOP(02:21:54)     26.03.2020 14:45:41    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93123 
    8   START              26.03.2020 12:23:47    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93127
    7   STOP(00:16:01)     26.03.2020 11:12:41    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93111
    6   START              26.03.2020 10:56:40    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93111
    5   STOP(02:10:01)     26.03.2020 10:23:41    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93B09
    4   START              26.03.2020 08:13:40    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93B09
    3   START              26.03.2020 07:23:41    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93123
    2   STOP(02:06:33)     26.03.2020 06:18:56    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93123
    1   START              26.03.2020 04:12:23    7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93123
```

0

I do not have much experience in programmable databases yet, so I don't even know if it can be done. If anyone will help, I will be grateful for your help)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can never have two STOPs in a row and you want the last START value, use `lag` to find the last start time. And subtract from the current time:

```
create table t (
  id int, status varchar2(5), date_cr timestamp, hash varchar2(32)
);
insert into t values (1, 'STOP', to_date ( '26.03.2020 14:45:41', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ), '7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93123' );    
insert into t values (2, 'START', to_date ( '26.03.2020 12:23:47', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ), '7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93127' );
insert into t values (3, 'STOP', to_date ( '26.03.2020 11:12:41', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ), '7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93111' );  
insert into t values (4, 'START', to_date ( '26.03.2020 10:56:40', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ), '7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93111' );
insert into t values (5, 'STOP', to_date ( '26.03.2020 10:23:41', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ), '7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93B09' );
insert into t values (6, 'START', to_date ( '26.03.2020 08:13:40', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ), '7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93B09' );
insert into t values (7, 'START', to_date ( '26.03.2020 07:23:41', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ), '7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93123' );
insert into t values (8, 'STOP', to_date ( '26.03.2020 06:18:56', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ), '7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93123' );
insert into t values (9, 'START', to_date ( '26.03.2020 04:12:23', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss' ), '7A8E93CA359A39133B6AAC93123' );
commit;

select id,
       status,
       date_cr,
       case 
         when status = 'STOP' then
           date_cr - lag ( date_cr ) over (
             order by date_cr 
           )
       end tm
from   t
order  by date_cr desc;

ID    STATUS    DATE_CR                           TM                    
    1 STOP      26-MAR-2020 14.45.41.000000000    +00 02:21:54.000000    
    2 START     26-MAR-2020 12.23.47.000000000    <null>                 
    3 STOP      26-MAR-2020 11.12.41.000000000    +00 00:16:01.000000    
    4 START     26-MAR-2020 10.56.40.000000000    <null>                 
    5 STOP      26-MAR-2020 10.23.41.000000000    +00 02:10:01.000000    
    6 START     26-MAR-2020 08.13.40.000000000    <null>                 
    7 START     26-MAR-2020 07.23.41.000000000    <null>                 
    8 STOP      26-MAR-2020 06.18.56.000000000    +00 02:06:33.000000    
    9 START     26-MAR-2020 04.12.23.000000000    <null>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is unrealistically cool, I didn't even think this request was possible. But 2 times STOP is possible, since it can include two different routes, and it is possible that 2 times will stop, and start also, you need to pay attention to the route hash

Comment: We could edit this query under such a taco variant and also pay attention to the hash, this is also very important, I would appreciate your help))

Comment: can you help me? , and then I did not find the answer to my question (((

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `could edit this query under such a taco variant and also pay attention to the hash` - could you clarify please?

Comment: Also, when there are two STOPs in a row, what should be the output? Please update the example to include this

Comment: i will try to add more details to you. routes come to me on API, they have 2 statuses (START, STOP). These routes have unique ids, they are in the HAS column. For an example, look at the data from id 3,2,1 (route started, stopped, and then started again). That is, in id 2, there should be a time difference between the start and stop of this route (2-1). The ids show that routes 4 and 3 started at the same time, but they did not stop at the same time (ids 5 and 9 respectively). But it may be that 2 different routes can stray one by one.